# Request.Form treats Newlines differently in TextArea in ASP .NET

Tags: asp.net, webforms, newline

I have two pages which have text area controls on them. When the user submits one page, newlines are treated as char(13) + char(10). But on the other page, newlines are treated as char(10). I've confirmed this by looking at the Request.Form dictionary.

The two pages are hosted in the same ASP .NET 4.0 Web Forms application, and the pages look exactly the same from a markup perspective. I'm logged in as the same user in the same browser.

When I use JavaScript to check for the existence of char 10 and char 13 in the control in the browser, both pages only include a char(10).

It seems as if IIS/ASP.NET is configured to handle form requests differently on the two pages, but I can't figure out where the difference would be. What causes this behavior?

Comment: Which operating system and browser?

Answer (score 1):

Different operating system use different combinations of characters to represent a new line.

On Windows it is CR + LF on Linux its LF and on Macs its CR.

CR = Carriage Return
LF = Line Feed

You can see the line ending characters if you copy / paste the text in Notepad++ and select View > Show all characters.

Comment: I know, and this is a good point, but I'm using Windows for this, and I'm using the same browser instance to submit both pages, so I don't see how that could make a difference.